# RC helicopter circuit power

Tags: power

I salvaged a few parts from an old RC heli. I also took the main circuit which controls the motors and has the built-in remote control. I want to power it but I don't have the original battery any more. I did some research and I found that the battery was a 3.7V 350mAh LiPo. How can I power the circuit with AA battery? I tried to buy the same battery (as the original) but couldn't.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LiPo 1S (single cell) gives about 3V fully discharged and 4.2V fully charged.

3 x AA Alkaline gives 3V discharged and about 4.5V+ newe.

3 x AA NimH gives about 3V to 3.6+V.

So 3 x AA should be OK.
Heli load was probably heavy - AA are OK for a few amps for a while but don't survive long being treated like a LiPo.